# Styling text inside tr?

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is my simplified markup:

```
<table class="kOverzicht kOverzichtFirst">
    <tr>
        woensdag 26&#47;02
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I already tried using a span or p element to wrap the text, but this was not allowed when I checked it with the validator.

What is the best way to style the text inside the tr? I cannot do this through the entire table because the actual table consists of multiple tr elements.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `<tr>`s are supposed to contain `<td>`s.

Comment: So if I simple wrap it in a td and give it a class this would be fine?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element

Comment: Yes. Do anything you want within the `td`.

Comment: Only `td` and `th` are valid children of `tr`. The text that is a direct child of a `tr` will be move above or below the `table` by the most browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `<td>` inside of the `<tr>`

`<table class="kOverzicht kOverzichtFirst">
    <tr>
        <td>woensdag 26&#47;02</td>
    </tr>
</table>`

`<tr>` tag just to define a table row..  A table cell `<td>` where the data is contained.

Answer (score 1):

Add the style text to the 
`<td>` tag to be created inside the `<tr>`.

Like

```
`<table class="kOverzicht kOverzichtFirst">
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 5px; font size="10""> </td>
</tr>
</table>`
```

This will help in styling specific lines only.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to wrap the text inside a td

```
<table class="kOverzicht kOverzichtFirst">
    <tr>
        <td>woensdag 26&#47;02</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then use the following css:

```
table.kOverzicht td {
   // define your css here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use td instead. For example,

```
<table class="kOverzicht kOverzichtFirst">
<tr>
    <td style="color:red;">
    woensdag 26&#47;02
    </td>
</tr>
```

Alternatively,

```
    <style>.kOverzicht td {color:red;}</style>

<table class="kOverzicht kOverzichtFirst">
<tr>
    <td>
    woensdag 26&#47;02
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered, you should really wrap the text in a cell container, a `td` or `th` element, and style that element. The details depend on the real structure of the table. In particular, a table with one column only does not usually make sense as a data table. If the text should span all the columns in the cell, you should use the `colspan` attribute, e.g. (assuming arbitrarily that the table has 5 columns)

```
<table class="kOverzicht kOverzichtFirst">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">woensdag 26/02</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- other rows go here -->
</table>
```

But to address the question as asked, you can style text inside a `tr` element like the text content of any other element, e.g.

```
tr { color: red; font-weight: bold }
```

However, with the invalid markup as in the question, the `tr` element has no content. You can see this by looking at the page in the developer tools of a browser. The browser has parsed it so that the text data precedes the entire table and the `tr` element is empty, `<tr></tr>`, so the style has no effect.

If you use valid markup with e.g. a `td` element inside `tr`, the text will be content in `td`. Setting text properties on `tr` may have an effect on it via inheritance; this happens for `color`, `font-weight`, and any other property.

It is possible to create a `tr` element with text directly inside it, but only using scripting, not via markup. Example:

```
<table id=t>
</table>
<script>
var row = document.createElement('tr');
row.textContent = 'woensdag 26/02';
document.getElementById('t').appendChild(row);
</script>
```

This is normally not recommended, for several reasons, but this is part of the answer to the question asked: to style text in a `tr` *directly* (and not via inheritance), you would need to create the `td` element with JavaScript.